# Reading List of JSONObjects from Postman request

Tags: java, json, spring, api

I have this Postman request.
[image]

With these headers:
[image]

Then my api is supposed to read the typeIdMap through a filter object with the @RequestBody annotation.
[image]

However when I try and read the typeIdMap
[image]

I get this error:[image]

You can see in the logs that typeIdMap is empty. However when I change typeIdMap to be a List<Map<String,Object>> I am able to retrieve the values. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the exact reasoning, but I figured it out...I was using org.json.JSONObject instead of org.json.simple.JSONObject. For some reason simple is the way to go when reading in the data.